# Form Submit connected to js event not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
  <form action="" id="search-form">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="rowElem">
        <input type="text">
        <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()">
        <div>Search</div>
        </a></div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("test");

});
});
</script>
```

When I submit the form I don't see the alert... What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Submitting the DOM object bypasses jQuery's event handler.

Comment: mm I see, so how do think I should go about it?

Comment: I'd get rid of the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Put your alert tag befor preventDeafault method. Iam not sure about this method. But if u r putting return false then after that any code u will put it will not exucute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like

```
<form action="" id="search-form">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="rowElem">
          <input name="query" type="text" /><br />
          <a class="search" href="#">Search</a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and

```
var form = $('#search-form');
$('.search', form).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var query = $('input[name="query"]', form).val();

    alert("test: " + query);

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qcN6r/6/)

If you want to use the params as part of a ajax request you can do something like

```
var form = $('#search-form');
$('.search', form).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var params = form.serialize();

    alert("test: " + form.serialize());

$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: params,
    ....
})   

});
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this will capture the click event, which is great, but it will not call submit on the form which is the OP's requested functionality

Comment: @DavidL yes, he can achieve the result he want using a similar method.

Comment: @Arun when I go into the click function, how can I retrieve what was written in the input text using event?

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove your obtrusive onclick event and bind to the link instead.

You can't alert AFTER you submit, since that would perform whatever action you give to the form (most likely taking you off the page.  If you insisted on doing so, the following would work.

```
<form action="" id="search-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="rowElem">
            <input id="name" type="text"></input>
            <a href="#" id="search" >Search</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>       

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search').bind('click', function () {
            // Alert the name BEFORE you do the form post
            alert($('#name).val());
            $('#search-form').submit(function(event){

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a working JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7jqUF/5/

If, instead, you wanted an AJAX solution, you'd want to do something other than a form post, such as an ajax post

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search').bind('click', function () {
            // Alert the name BEFORE you do the form post
            alert($('#name).val());
            $.post('/ServerUrl/method', { name: $('#name').val() });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Code as is isn't functional :$

Comment: Np but  I mean with my modification, I still wasn't able to make it work

Comment: @Kam I have added a working JSFiddle of some modifications.  However, be careful on your intended action of the form post.  If you need to stay on the page, the form post will not help you, which is why I also added the AJAX method.  Hope this clears things up for you!

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I upvoted it, but I found the selected answer an easier implementation of the issue on hand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. After removing the submit code from the `$(document).ready` function

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit();">
```

Comment: This is still an obtrusive solution and does not take advantage of his jQuery

Comment: yep this as simple and easy to implement. And why use jQuery when not required

Comment: It's simple and easy to implement but extremely bad for modular, oop javascript.  The same thing could be done in a non-obtrusive manner with regular javascript...jQuery just makes it easier.  At the end of the day the preferable pattern should always favor non-obtrusive javascript

Comment: The "modular ,oop JS preference is nowhere mentioned in the question BTW. So a simple solution is enough for the help we all are trying to provide. And I have posted the solution as per my understanding which you can also do/might have done by posting an answer.

Comment: The simple solution is by no means the right solution for the industry and part of our mission here should be to encourage proper patterns.  In addition, the OP specifically was trying to use jQuery, which was not included in your answer.  I'm not downvoting your answer since technically it does accomplish the job.  At the end of the day, we're allowed our ideological differences